# C# A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected

Tags: c#, sockets

So am trying to send a packet but am keep getting this error

Any help would be awesome!

Thanks a lot!

Error Message:
A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied

Code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] packetData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textBox1.Text);

        const string ip = "127.0.0.1";
        const int port = 5588;


        var ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip), port);


        var client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        client.SendTo(packetData, ep);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried connecting the `Socket`?

Comment: I posted a correction to your code; you've created the Endpoint and the Socket; you need to call Connect on the Socket with the Endpoint as a param.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> var client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)

This creates a socket that will use TCP (which is a *stream protocol*). If you want to call `Socket.SendTo` on a connection oriented socket, you have to connect it first, through a call to `Socket.Connect`.

If you are intending to send datagrams only, it is a better choice to use UDP instead, which does not require connecting at all.

> var client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp)

Answer (score 1):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    byte[] packetData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textBox1.Text);

    const string ip = "75.126.77.26";
    const int port = 5588;


    var ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip), port);


    var client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    client.Connect(ep);
    client.SendTo(packetData, ep);
}
```

for clarity, added this line:

```
    client.Connect(ep);
```

Answer (score -2):

I think what you are looking for is calling `client.Connect` before calling `client.SendTo`. You'll also want to call `client.Connected` after you call connect to ensure you are connected.

This help page has an example of using the socket object: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2b86d684%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.

```
    // Connect to the host using its IPEndPoint.
    s.Connect(hostEndPoint);

    if (!s.Connected)
    {
      // Connection failed, try next IPaddress.
      strRetPage = "Unable to connect to host";
      s = null;
      continue;
    }
```

Comment: Using the Connected property like this is useless. It will always be true. I'm not sure why everybody does that. Even if it could be false this kind of error handling is not helpful.